# how to execute csh script from a tcl program

Tags: tcl

I am trying to execute a csh script from a tcl script and stroe the outcome of the csh script in a tcl list. I am using the tclsh8.5 interpreter.

I have done the following

```
set varList [exec /bin/csh -c cshScript arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4]
```

but the list is empty. If I execute the csh script in a terminal it produces the right result.

I have also tried:

```
set varList [exec /bin/csh -c cshScript arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 >@stdout 2>@stderr]
```

but again the list is empty
What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: What happens if you start an interactive tclsh session and enter the `exec ...` command?

Comment: What is the exit status of the csh script?

Comment: If I execute the command (either of the above) in a tclsh shell then I get no output either. I only get the right list if I execute the csh script in a csh shell.

Comment: The exit status of the csh script is 'exit 0'

Comment: you get no output because you're capturing it in the variable: what's in the variable?

Comment: Long ago when I still used csh regularly, I had similar looking problems because csh was not pulling in my profile (paths, env vars, etc) when invoked from another program.  You may need to take explicit action to make sure that any environment your script needs gets explicitly set correctly.  Hope this helps, it's been a decade or so since I switched from csh to bash for daily use.

Comment: even if I do not capture it in a variable there is no output so executing the following command in a tclsh8.5:exec /bin/csh -c cshScript arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 >@stdout 2>@stderr gives no output either.

Comment: In any case I rewrote the csh script in tcl and now it works like charm! Thanks!